# pyspark: substring a string using dynamic index

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
filtered_df = filtered_df.withColumn('POINT', substring('POINT', instr(filtered_df.POINT, "#"), 30))
```

I need to get the first index of the # in the string and then pass that index as the substring starting position as above. What would be the way to do that?

This gives me `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

Comment: Do you really need substring function or the index? Seems you could `''.join(string.split("#")[1:])`

Comment: `filtered_df = filtered_df.withColumn('POINT', split(filtered_df['POINT'], "#")[1:])` gives startPos and length must be the same type. Got <class 'int'> and <class 'NoneType'>, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The `substring` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` only takes fixed starting position and length. However your approach will work using an expression.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

d = [{'POINT': 'The quick # brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'},
    {'POINT': 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.# The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

df.withColumn('POINT', F.expr("substring(POINT, instr(POINT, '#'), 30)")).show(2, False)

+------------------------------+
|POINT                         |
+------------------------------+
|# brown fox jumps over the laz|
|# The quick brown fox jumps ov|
+------------------------------+
```