# Pyspark create a column with a substring with variable length

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, substring

I need to get a substring from a column of a dataframe that starts at a fixed number and goes all the way to the end. So, for example, for one row the substring starts at 7 and goes to 20, for another it starts at 7 and goes to 21.
How can I define this within the colonn creation?

```
columns = ["key", "value"]
data = [("key1", "09-2021_Books"), ("key2", "09-2021_Cds, value4"), ("key3", "09-2021_Computers"),]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
```

I'd like a column that starts after "_" and has only "Books", "Cds", "Computers".
I tried with

```
df.withColumn("items", substring("value", 7, length("value") )).show()
```

This is the traceback:

```
TypeError: Column is not iterable
---> 30 df.withColumn("items", substring("value", 7, length("value") )).show()
 31 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in substring(str, pos, len)
   2944     """
   2945     sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
-> 2946     return Column(sc._jvm.functions.substring(_to_java_column(str), pos, len))
   2947 
   2948 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1294 
   1295     def __call__(self, *args):
-> 1296         args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
   1297 
   1298         command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
```

Comment: use the sql function within an `expr('substr(x, 1, n)')`. the pyspark functions accept specific inputs only and  `substring` accepts column as frst input and integers for the rest of the inputs

Comment: [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71242733/8279585) is quite similar and can be helpful in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `split` function from `pyspark.sql.functions` will work for you.
As a second argument of `split` we need to pass a regular expression, so just provide a regex matching first 8 characters. After the split just take the second entry of the resulting array (0-based).

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

columns = ["key", "value"]
data = [("key1", "09-2021_Books"), ("key2", "09-2021_Cds, value4"), ("key3", "09-2021_Computers"),]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

df.withColumn("items", sf.split("value", "^.{8}").getItem(1)).show()
```

However, in your example I think that better option would be to split this column by a delimiter:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

columns = ["key", "value"]
data = [("key1", "09-2021_Books"), ("key2", "09-2021_Cds, value4"), ("key3", "09-2021_Computers"),]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

df.withColumn("items", sf.split("value", "_", 2).getItem(1)).show()
```

Third argument of `split` controls how many entries resulting array will contain.