# Can I create a new column using a variable amount of characters from the right of an existing column in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that essentially looks like the following table:

| Product | Name |
| --- | --- |
| abcd - 12 | abcd |
| xyz - 123543 | xyz |

I am hoping to create a new column (UPC) that only contains the numbers to the right of the hyphen in the Product column.

I know in Excel I can use the Right function with len and find but from what I can tell, those do not have equivalents in Python.

I have tried creating 2 new columns, LastHyphen (because the product column could have more than 1 hyphen) and ProductLength. I was then hoping to plug those into the substring function but I keep getting a "Column is not iterable" error.

```
df4 = df3.withColumn("LastHyphen",length(col("PRODUCT"))-locate('-',reverse(col("PRODUCT"))))
df4 = df4.withColumn("ProductLength",length(col("PRODUCT")))
df4 = df4.withColumn("UPC", substring("PRODUCT", df4.LastHyphen, df4.ProductLength - df4.LastHyphen))
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

I am hoping to get an output like:

| Product | UPC |
| --- | --- |
| abcd - 12 | 12 |
| xyz - 123543 | 123543 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73907074/pyspark-create-a-column-with-a-substring-with-variable-length) and the answer there involves a regexp split.

In your specific circumstance it might be easiest to do a regular expression to extract the UPC from the string.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_extract

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(product="abcd - 12", name="abcd"),
        Row(product="xyz - 123543", name="xyz"),
        Row(product="xyz - abc - 123456", name="xyz - abc"),
    ]
)

df.withColumn("UPC", regexp_extract(col("product"), ".* - ([0-9]{1,})", 1)).show()
```

```
+------------------+---------+------+
|           product|     name|   UPC|
+------------------+---------+------+
|         abcd - 12|     abcd|    12|
|      xyz - 123543|      xyz|123543|
|xyz - abc - 123456|xyz - abc|123456|
+------------------+---------+------+
```